# WCF service with Factory attribute on .svc is not working on web server (IIS6), but is locally using IIS7?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, iis-6

I am working on implementing a non web.config approach of WCF services using the factory attribute on the .svc file per [Rick Strahl's blog post](http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/896411.aspx):

Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"

Locally, I am running IIS7 in Visual Studio 2008 and have no problem, but when I deploy to my web server (currently running IIS6), I am getting an authentication error in the event log:

> Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException:
>   The service
>   '/Services/ResourcesService.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: IIS specified
>   authentication schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication,
>   Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one
>   authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest,
>   Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
>   Change the IIS settings so that only a
>   single authentication scheme is used..
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: IIS specified authentication schemes
>   'IntegratedWindowsAuthentication,
>   Anonymous', but the binding only
>   supports specification of exactly one
>   authentication scheme. Valid
>   authentication schemes are Digest,
>   Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous.
>   Change the IIS settings so that only a
>   single authentication scheme is used. 
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.SetBindingCredentialBasedOnHostedEnvironment(ServiceEndpoint
>   serviceEndpoint, AuthenticationSchemes
>   supportedSchemes)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost
>   host, IDictionary`2
>   implementedContracts, String
>   multipleContractsErrorMessage)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.WebScriptServiceHost.OnOpening()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)

After doing some Googling, I changed my authentication settings on the .svc folder within my project (on the server) to only anonymous authentication, but it did not work.  I still get web service failed on the calls.  IIS7 by default only had anonymous.

I do not have any entries in my web.config for the services (I stripped them out per this pattern).

I am using a nant script to deploy the website to the server and use this also locally to verify the script was not causing the issue.

Any known issue with this?  IIS 6 not able to handle?

Answer (score 5):

I got this error ...

Checked my web site properties in IIS Manager and found both Anonymous and Integrated Windows Authentication were ticked, so un-ticked Integrated, but it still wouldn't work.

Eventually spotted a post that mentioned restarting IIS ... did that and things worked !!

Comment: confirmed, IIS 6 is so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between IIS 6 and IIS 7 with respect to WCF is the bindings that they support. For example IIS 6 supports basichttpbinding but not nettcpbinding.

The other thing to watch out for is if IIS 6 is configured to serve .svc files, that minimum .net framework 3.0 is installed.

Comment: The website is using 3.5 framework, which is installed locally and on the web server respectively.  The confusing part -- the services are fine on the web server if I have the web.config entries and no factory attribute on the .svc file.